# modrewrite -f being ignored

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ive got a image cache system that im using to generate certain image sizes as require.  Im using modrewrite to check for the file and call the image creation system if it doesnt exist. The problem im having is that it is calling the image creation system even if the image does exist!

The modrewrite is simple enough (sites in the images sub directory)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /images/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I even tried removing the `-d` incase the directory check was confusing it.  Ive now got it so that it checks the file exists inside the index.php code - which reports that it does.

I use the url `images/cache/140x20/Test.JPG` in the html - the file exists, so the `RewriteCond` should not call the index.php code - but it does for some reason?

Im sure its something obvious but i just cant figure it out

Comment: It sounds like there's a path mix-up. Is the htaccess file in the document root? Can you add a `R=302` as a flag to see what path it's really getting?

Comment: the .htaccess is in the images directory.  Using R=302 i get the correct path expected www.domain.com/images/index.php?id=cache/140x20/Test.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the .htaccess is in the images directory. Using R=302 i get the correct path expected www.domain.com/images/index.php?id=cache/140x20/Test.JPG

That's weird. I was testing under a subdirectory and was getting some unexpected values for `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`. But I was able to get the check to work correctly by reconstructing from the document root. Maybe my understanding of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` or the underlying mechanism apache uses to make URI-path to file-path is different than what I expected.

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}${REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}${REQUEST_URI} !-d
# and maybe for good measure
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
```

---

EDIT:

If your extensions are in all caps but the image filename extensions are always all lowercase, you can use a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) and define a map using the `tolower` function:

(somewhere in your server or vhost config:

```
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
```

Then in your htaccess file (above your other rules), change the filenames to lowercase:

```
# first check to make sure request doesn't already have all lowercase image extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|bmp|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpe?g|png|bmp|gif)$ /$1.${lowercase:$2} [NC,L]
```

You can also do something similar with the entire filename, or the entire path.

Comment: Does the same. I just noticed the extension is lowercase in the actual directory structure.  It could be case differences, could that cause it.  I tried altering the URL but it doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: @AdrianBrown !-f is definitely case sensitive.

Comment: @AdrianBrown Just for debugging, what url do you get redirected to if you change your rule to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /images/index.php?id=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [R,L,QSA]`?

Comment: Right, it turns out it is the case sensitivity causing the problems.  But is it possible to do case-insensitive filename checking.  [NC] doesnt work on filenames it seems

Comment: @AdrianBrown don't think you can make the actual `-f` check case insensitive. You can make the URI (or part of it) all caps or all lowercase with a a [RewriteMap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1620340/851273) and then do the `-f`, but that requires access to server/vhost config, though. But if your physical image filenames have capital letters, this won't be sufficient either. See the edit for an example